# Change background color of Div to value of variable using Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css, background, styles

I have been trying to change the color of a div to a randomly generated hex color code which is passed into a variable. How do I make this work?

HTML

```
<p id="demo">NULL</p>
<button onclick="generatePassword()">Generate</button>
<div id="showcase" style="background: #FFFFFF; width: 200px; height: 200px; margin: 20px; border-radius: 3px;"></div>
```

JAVASCRIPT

```
var result = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;

function generatePassword() {
    var length = 6,
        charset = "ABCDEF0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = "#" + retVal;
    return document.getElementById('showcase').style.backgroundColor = retVal;
}
```

Link to fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/elliotsoomro/gngg89t5/5/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You've almost got it, here's the fix: https://jsfiddle.net/yL1uu6bz/1/

```
var result = document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML;

function generatePassword() {
    var length = 6,
        charset = "ABCDEF0123456789",
        retVal = "";
    for (var i = 0, n = charset.length; i < length; ++i) {
        retVal += charset.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * n));
    }
    var finalVal = "#" + retVal;
    document.getElementById('demo').innerHTML = finalVal;
    return document.getElementById('showcase').style.backgroundColor = finalVal;
}
```

I simply added the hash symbol and appended it in the same way you've already done for outputting the value (`"#" + retVal`), I added this in a variable (`finalVal`) and output it instead.

Comment: Thank you so much! Have been trying to figure out this for the whole day!

Comment: @E.Soomro, Always the simple ones that get me too!

Comment: @E.Soomro, if an answer helps you out, please mark it as correct so it might help others in the future...